# htaccess redirect based on Referral

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm looking for `htaccess` redirection code.

I want to redirect `http://mywebsite.com/pic.jpg` to `http://example.com` if the referral is anywhere in `http://foo.com`.

Also I want to redirect `http://website.com/pic2.jpb` to `http://example2.com` if the referral is anywhere in `http://foo2.com`

I already saw some examples of this implemented in htaccess, but I didn't see how would you do it for multi conditions like the above, also note that I want to redirect based on the file name `pic.jpg`/`pic2.jpg` not file extension.

**Code I tried:** .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %(HTTP_REFERER) ^http://foo\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \pic.jpg https://example.com [R]
```

Comment: This seems inadvisable.  You appear to want one domain name for every picture.  How do you expect that to scale?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That was an example, I want to know the code for the above example to be able to customize it for my use. Thanks

Comment: Show what code you have tried and what isn't working. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Just vote to close as too broad, if you think the answer won't fit on one page.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I actually think the answer would be very simple, if he shows what code he is currently using.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara see my edit, I included the code I tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't have multiple `RewriteCond` blocks.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://foo\.com [NC]
RewriteRule pic\.jpg http://mywebsite.com/pic.jpg [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://foo2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule pic\.jpg http://website.com/pic2.jpg [R]
```

Alternately, if you want to send both to the same URL, you could use the `OR` flag, that must be included after each conditional rewrite line except the last one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://foo\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://foo2\.com [NC]
```

Comment: but I don't want to redirect both of them to the same page, if you read my question, there is `pic.jpg` and `pic2.jpg` and example.com and example2.com

Comment: @kalin I've updated my answer with both posibilities.

Comment: what if the referral is not the main `foo.com` domain, what if it's a subdirectory, does the code above cover that case too?

Comment: @kalin Yes, the conditions are regular expressions that match the beginning of the URL (as set by the `^` flag).

Comment: the above code didn't work for me, I placed mywebsite.com/pic.jpg in foo.com, when I visited foo.com pic.jpg was shown correctly in foo.com, it didn't redirect to example.com

Comment: @kalin Try it now, I think the miss-placed back slashes in your `RewriteRule` may have been the issue. Also make sure your browser is sending a referer, they can be modified or disabled by settings and exteneions.